# Using PHP variables globally in another script files

Tags: php

I'm trying to access variables globally.

I created a file `test1.php` and in it I wrote

```
<?php
    $a = 5;
    $b = 7;
?>
```

And in another file `test2.php` I wrote,

```
<?php 
    global $a, $b;
    echo $a + $b;
?>
```

but result was 0.

So,

1. Can't I use `$a, $b` in other page?
2. Do I need to use session for this?

Comment: only if you include the file. Right now, the left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing.

Comment: if you don't `include` one script to the other you'd need to use `$_SESSION`, yes. Or pass it as parameter from one script to the other

Comment: [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are “undefined variable” errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and) --- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: *"So Could it be used in other page? or should I use session ?"* - That is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to introduce a file called `globals.php` and have all your variables there.

```
<?php
    $a = 5;
    $b = 7;
?>
```

Then in your `test2.php` file, include the `globals.php`. Then you can use your variables.

```
include "globals.php"
echo $a + $b;
```

The `global` keyword can be used if you are to use your variables inside a function, without passing them inside the function.

like,

```
include "globals.php"

function calculate(){
    global $a, $b;
    return $a + $b;
}

echo calculate();
```

If you are not going to use a file like `globals.php`, your option is to save the values in `$_SESSION`, which can be quite ugly when you have more stuff! But still can use.

Since you state that you are beginner, It is always good to keep stuff separate. Global variables separately, Functions separately, etc... and include them in the files that you are going to use them. This separation helps you to manage stuff easily when they grow. (ex: if it is a function that you want to debug into, you know where it is...)

Hope this helped you! Thanks.